# When I click on button the entire <form> tag should be loaded event in java script

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling

How can I implement the `on-click` event in javascript for below use-case

When I click the **button** after the entire **`<form>`** tag should be loading.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit a form and call upon a function when you click the submit button, you can do this :

`<input type="submit" value"Submit" onclick="return yourFunction();" />`

Answer (score 0):

With HTML 5 [form attribute](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/) on the button;

```
<form id="myForm" method="get" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>

<input type="submit" form="myForm" />
```